# How can I edit the percent of progress bar in Ant design?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progress-bar, ant-design-pro

I am now using react js and importing the ant design progress component(see [https://ant.design/components/progress/](https://www.stackoverflow.com/))
But I fail to edit the percentage of the bar with javascript after it is displayed.
I initiate it will this Html code.

```
<Progress id="progressBar" 

strokeColor={{from: '#108ee9', to: '#87d068'}}

percent={0}

status="active"/>
```

I tried to call `progressBar.percent` to edit but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store your pecentage in `useState`

```
const [percent, setPercent] = useState(0)
```

and pass it to Progress:

```
<Progress id="progressBar" 
strokeColor={{from: '#108ee9', to: '#87d068'}}
percent={percent}
status="active"/>
```

and then simply call `setPercent(50)` to change your state.

This is fundamental principe how to work with states in react.
You can read more [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)